# Creating Dependency Properties for custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I am trying to create a `DependencyProperty` for my custom `Control`.

I wish to be able to set a `FileList` property, which will be set as a string, separated by commas, but stored in memory as a list of strings.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class FileTypeListControl : Control 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FileTypeListProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "FileTypeList",
            typeof(List<string>),
            typeof(FileTypeListControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(new List<string>() { ".txt" },
                OnFileTypeListPropertyChanged,
                OnCoerceFileTypeListProperty),
                OnValidateFileTypeListPropety);  

    public List<string> FileTypeList
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<string>)GetValue(FileTypeListProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(FileTypeListProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static void OnFileTypeListPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public static object OnCoerceFileTypeListProperty(
        DependencyObject sender, object data)
    {
        if (data is string)
        {
            var val = (data as string).Split(new char[] { ',' });
            return val;
        }
        else if (data is List<string>)
        {
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }

    public static bool OnValidateFileTypeListPropety(object data)
    {
        return true;
    }
}


<local:FileTypeListControl x:Name="control"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           FileTypeList=".xml,.java,.exe"/>
```

Now, the problem is it doesn't like the the way I specified the `FileTypeList` property in the xaml. I was under the impression the `OnCoerceFileListProperty` method was there to coerce the value into the suitable type, which is what I am doing.

I could use a value converter, but this doesn't feel correct every time I wish to re-use the control .

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the purpose of the CoerceValueCallback to perform type conversions. This task is usually performed by TypeConverters, like this:

```
public class StringListConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return ((string)value).Split(',');
    }
}

...

[TypeConverter(typeof(StringListConverter))]
public IList<string> FileTypeList
{
    get { return (IList<string>)GetValue(FileTypeListProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FileTypeListProperty, value); }
}
```

Please note also that declaring the property as `IList<string>` provides greater flexibility than `List<string>`.

You should also avoid to use an expression like `new List<string>() { ".txt" }` as the default value of your dependency property, as this value is used for all "instances" of your property. When you e.g. add a string to the `FileTypeList` property in one control instance, this change will also take place in other control instance, as long as they have the default property value.

The default value should be `null` for all reference type properties. You may then set the real default value in the control's constructor:

```
public FileTypeListControl()
{
    SetCurrentValue(FileTypeListProperty, new List<string>() { ".txt" });
}
```

Comment: Great answer thanks. I didn't know about TypeConverter, only IValueConverter. You mention Coerce shouldn't make changes to the type? It should only manipulate the current type, such as trimming a string?

Comment: Exactly. More precisely, it manipulates the current *value*. It can't change the type of the property.